# Why are all if-else statements printing no matter the input?

Tags: c++, if-statement

When inputting any letter (F, R, or G) every if statement prints in the compiler.
Im not sure as to why this is the case but some answers would be nice!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int tmp;
float precip;
char frg;

cout << "Fall 2018 Automated \"Bruin\" Golf Course Sprinkler System" << endl;
cout << endl << "What is the temperature in degrees(F)? ";
cin >> tmp;
cout << "How much precipitation today (in inches)? ";
cin >> precip;
cout << "The Golf Course grass divisions are F-Fairways, R-Rough, G-Greens.";
cout << endl << "Which do you choose (FRG)? ";
cin >> frg;

if (frg == 'R' && precip < 0.835 && tmp > 38)
    {
        cout << endl << "Given the temperature is " << tmp << " degrees and " << precip << " inches of precipitation today." << endl;
        cout << "The Rough on the Golf Course will be watered.";
    } else
        {
            cout << endl << "Given the temperature is " << tmp << " degrees and " << precip << " inches of precipitation today." << endl;
            cout << "The Rough on the Golf Course will NOT be watered.";
        }

if (frg == 'F' && precip < 0.525 && tmp > 38)
    {
        cout << endl << "Given the temperature is " << tmp << " degrees and " << precip << " inches of precipitation today." << endl;
        cout << "The Fairways on the Golf Course will be watered.";
    } else
        {
            cout << endl << "Given the temperature is " << tmp << " degrees and " << precip << " inches of precipitation today." << endl;
            cout << "The Fairways on the Golf Course will NOT be watered.";
        }

if (frg == 'G' && precip < 0.325 && tmp > 38)
    {
        cout << endl << "Given the temperature is " << tmp << " degrees and " << precip << " inches of precipitation today." << endl;
        cout << "The Greens on the Golf Course will be watered.";
    } else
        {
            cout << endl << "Given the temperature is " << tmp << " degrees and " << precip << " inches of precipitation today." << endl;
            cout << "The Greens on the Golf Course will NOT be watered.";
        }
return 0;
}
```

Even when i input R when asked for the frg variable, all the if statements are printed in the compiler. Please help!

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "All the if statements are printed". Could you please give expected output vs current output?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run the program one line at a time, and examine the values of all variables after each statement gets executed, what observations did you make? Do you know how to use your debugger? Have you been told, or are you aware that knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer? And if you did that already, you would've figured out exactly why "all if-else statements printing", because that's what you told your computer to do. Every `if-else` statement in the shown code prints something.

Comment: your logic seems correct, it should only go into one of those if statements based on your input character.  are you sure it's not hitting one IF and then the other 2 ELSES??

Comment: The else part of the other two statements are getting executed because the condition is false. You need to check the character and the measurements separately.

Comment: You can [edit] your post to clarify it, as requested in the comments. This will make it possible to answer.

Comment: When you type in `R`, are the other two `if` statements printing their `else` statements, or the true part statements? Cause if the `else` statements are ran, then that’s normal.

Answer (score 3):

> All the if statements are printed

That is not what is happening. Only one of the `if` statements are printed, but the other 2 `else` statements (from the other 2 `if`s) are also printed because the `if` will fail.

I commented your code a bit.

```
if (frg == 'R' && precip < 0.835 && tmp > 38) {
    // ... your code
} else {
    // Execution will reach this block when frg != R || precip > 0.835 || tmp < 38
    // So if you typed F or G, this else will be executed
}

if (frg == 'F' && precip < 0.525 && tmp > 38) {
    // ... your code
} else {
    // Execution will reach this block when frg != F || precip > 0.525 || tmp > 38
    // So if you typed R or G, this else will be executed
}

if (frg == 'G' && precip < 0.325 && tmp > 38) {
    // ... your code
} else {
    // Execution will reach this block when frg != G || precip > 0.325 || tmp < 38
    // So if you typed R or F, this else will be executed
}
```

As to what you should do to 'fix' this, i can't really suggest anything because I don't know what the desired behavior is.

Hope this clears things up,

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

your logic seems correct, it should only go into one of those if statements based on your input character. are you sure it's not hitting one IF and then the other 2 ELSES??

you can add

```
 return;
```

to the end of your the logic inside of your { } brackets, that would ensure that only one logic { } bracket would execute...

or you would need a nested if/else statement to make sure only 1 { } bracket is executed.

as you have it now you are running 1 if, and then 2 elses based on the character